# Firefox timer for addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In one of my firefox addon I need to use setTimeout function of timer. I wrote the following code:

```
exports.main = function() {
    const widgets = require("sdk/widget");
    const data = require("sdk/self").data;
    const tmr = require('timers');

    var player = widgets.Widget({
      id: "player",
      width: 72,
      label: "Player",
      contentURL: data.url("content.html"),
      contentScriptFile: data.url("script.js")
    });

    player.port.on("play", function() {
      player.content = "1024x980";
      tmr.setTimeout(setTimer, 500);
    });

    function setTimer()
    {
        player.contentURL = data.url("content.html");
    }
};
```

But it did not fire the setTimer function after 500ms. Please help me as a newbie of firefox addon development.

Comment: Can you tell if `player.content = "1024x980";` is getting run?

Comment: Yes, it is getting run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Its nothing but only two problem in my code. First one is contentURL is not working in this case. Second one is call method before definition.

```
exports.main = function() {
    const widgets = require("sdk/widget");
    const data = require("sdk/self").data;
    const tmr = require('timers');

    var player = widgets.Widget({
      id: "player",
      width: 72,
      label: "Player",
      contentURL: data.url("content.html"),
      contentScriptFile: data.url("script.js")
    });

    function setTimer()
    {
        player.content = "your text here";
    }

    player.port.on("play", function() {
      player.content = "1024x980";
      tmr.setTimeout(setTimer, 500);
    });    
};
```